# Let $G$ be a finite group and $A \le G$. If $G=AA^g$ for some $g$ then $G=A$.

Tags: group-theory

Hi: I could try to prove there is a bijection $f$ from $A$ into $G$. There is a bijection $A\to A^g$. Then $|G|= |A||A^g|/|A\cap A^g|=2|A|/|A\cap A^g|$. If $|A\cap A^g|=2$ then $G=A$, because $G$ is finite. But how do I prove it? And how do I find $f$? Suppose $f(a)=aa^g$. If I can prove $f$ is onto then $A=G$. But if $g \in G$ then $g=xy^g$ for $x,y\in A$. Why would $x=y$? Another way would be to find an injection from $G$ into $A$.

P.S.: $a^g:= g^{-1}ag$. $A^g:= g^{-1}Ag$.

Comment: What does $a^g$ mean? Is it $gag^{-1}$?

Comment: Would the [tag:group-actions] tag be appropriate here?

Comment: @N.S.: Yes. I'm not supposed to know actions yet.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** I assume that $A \leq G$ means subgroup.

You know that for each $x \in G$ there exists $y,z \in A$ such that
$$x=yg^{-1}zg$$

Set $x =g$ to deduce that $g \in A$. Show then that $AA^g \subseteq A$.

Comment: How can you set $\;g=x\;$ ? I mean, you can, and then you get $\;yx^{-1}zx=...?\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio Substitute the other way (let $x=g$, not $g=x$; you can't choose $g$ arbitrarily as it is given): $g = yg^{-1}zg$

Comment: Aaaah! $1=yg^{-1}z$, $g^{-1}=y^{-1}z^{-1}, g^{-1}\in A, g\in A$. But then $A^g=A$ and $AA^g=AA=A$ because $A$ is a subgroup. Thanks a lot N.S.

Comment: Yeah, now I finally read it carefully: it is $\;AA^g\;$ , for some $\;g\in G\;$ , **not** $\;AA^G\;$ ...thanx/

Comment: @DonAntonio $g \in G$ is fixed in the statement of the problem.  And yes, the statement being only in the title can make the reading a bit tricky :)

Comment: I am seeing $G$ does not have to be finite for the statement to be true!